# help me to understand about this simple malloc in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Here is the code that i want to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{

    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int)),i;

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question: I allocated 5 * int size of memory but why it takes more than 5 ineteger?
Thnx

Answer (score 4):

You reserved space for 5 integers. For the other 95 integers, you're writing into space that is reserved for other purposes. Your program may or may not crash, but you should expect that it will fail one way or another.

Comment: You're using space that's reserved for other purposes. That memory may or may not be written into by anything that you call during the life of your program. If nothing else uses that memory, then you'll get back what you put into it. But you shouldn't think that this program is "working". For example: suppose `printf` made some calls to `malloc` as it executes. If that were to happen, you might get different results. On the other hand, it's possible that `printf` does call `malloc` as it executes, and it just happens not to use the memory that you're overwriting. You just don't know.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't "take" more than 5 integers; you are just invoking undefined behavior. You can't expect the code to "succeed" even if you are seeing it work on your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 'taking' more than 5 integers : you allocated `5 * sizeof(int)` and invoke undefined behavior by accessing memory beyond this size.

There's no question as whether you should set `MAX` to 10, 1024 or 100000 : the code is fundamentally wrong, and the fact that it didn't fail when you ran it doesn't make it less wrong. Tools like [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) may help you detect such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

- You are allocating 5 integers, anything you write or read more than this is incorrect
- OS protection boundaries are 1 page, which generally means 4k.
- Even if you have allocated only 5 integers, you still have the rest of the page unprotected. That is how buffer overflows and many program misbehaviors happen
- I am betting if your MAX is set to 1025, you will have seg fault (assuming this is your program)

Comment: OS protection boundaries have nothing to do with it. There's no requirement that malloc will return a block that's aligned to a page. It may well return a block that shares a page with other blocks, and/or crosses page boundaries.

Comment: Dan, I am not stating it as a requirement. But if that was at the beginning of a page boundary, that would be the most leeway someone would get. In fact, in the above app, I can reasonably argue this is the only thing in the heap, and hence starts at the page boundary.

Comment: It's unlikely that OS pages have a direct bearing on which blocks of memory are parceled out by `malloc`. It's more likely to be correct if you simply say that malloc returned a block from an otherwise-unused chunk of memory.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't perform bounds checking on arrays.  If you have a 5-element array, C will happily let you assign to `arr[5]`, `arr[100]`, or even `arr[-1]`.

If you're lucky, this will merely overwrite unused memory and your program will work anyway.

If you're unlucky, you'll overwrite other variables in your program, the metadata for `malloc`, or the OS, and Bad Things will happen.  Get used to seeing the phrase "segmentation fault".

Comment: +1 for guessing the OP's unstated assumption that somehow the compiler or executed code should visibly complain about running past the end of an array (or memory block).